# Run node.js app remotely on WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I have node.js installed on Vagrant and WebStorm access to a project on shared folder via VirtualBox.

Can I run node.js application on WebStorm and see the output on WebStorm (Terminal or SSH)? At the moment I have to keep switching to Putty to run it to see the output,  its gets quite tiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Node.js applications remotely is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-6136](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6136) for updates.
Debugging remote applications is possible (using `Node.js Remote Debug` run configuration - see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application#RunninganddebuggingNode.jsapplication-DebuggingNode.jsappthatrunsremotely). But you can't see the remote process output in WebStorm console, as Stdout of it is not accessible via debug protocol WebStorm uses for remote debugging. Related feature request: [WEB-17013](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17013)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about PHPStorm?

Comment: Just the same. they share the same code based - all javascript features in PHPStorm are actually 'hosted' by WebStorm, PHPStorm just includes WebStorm stuff

Comment: It seems remote interpreter is now available in webstorm:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1974#comment=27-1268003

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available through ssh on Webstorm 2017.1

Scroll down to **Configuring a remote Node.js interpreter on a host accessible through SSH connection** in the link below:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-node-js-interpreters.html